# Temporary failure in name resolution, Ping not working, Missing /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: networking, dns, display-resolution, systemd, resolv.conf

```
$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

So I checked for `/etc/resolv.conf` but its missing

```
$ ll /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jul 31  2020 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

$ ll /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
ls: cannot access '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf': No such file or directory
```

This is a Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS system. I have not tried setting up a temporary name server (what's a quick way to do this?). I think name resolution was working previously the last time I checked a year ago.

What else can I do to solve the problem in `Temporary failure in name resolution`? Thanks

Comment: Updated question with these details

Comment: The stub-resolv.conf is a generated file.  Please add the output of ps auxww | grep systemd   and resolvectl status  (not sure it's resolvectl for 20.04, maybe it was systemd-resolve status) (note, not systemd-resolved)

Comment: Set a temporary nameserver: `sudo -i` and next: `echo "nameserver  8.8.8.8"  >>  /etc/resolv.conf` and finally: `exit` Now can you: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` Please note that this is a temporary hack that will likely not survive a reboot.

Comment: Problem solved after making some disk space available through `tunefs`. Deleted files didnt free up disk space until that was done. Thanks everyone